# JQuery 'animate' function doesn't smoothly animate width of Bootstrap progress bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, progress-bar, width, bootstrap-4

I am designing an animated progress bar with jQuery / Bootstrap. My progress bar has 8 'steps', each one representing 12.5% of the width of the entire progress bar.

I've designed a function that works well when animating bar changes from steps one through four. However, when step five comes along, for some reason the bar animates to 100% before going back down to 50%. The same thing happens at steps 6, 7, and 8.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Why is my animate() function jumping the width of the bar to 100% at step 5 before toning it back down to 62.5%?

**javascript**

```
window.total = 0;
window.target = 8;
var progress_percent_full = window.total / window.target;

function update_progress_bar() {
  progress_percent_full = (window.total / window.target) * 100;
  new_width = progress_percent_full + "%";

  $("#progress-bar").animate({
    width: new_width,
  });
  $("#progress-bar").text(total);
}

$("#button").click(function() {
  window.total = window.total + 1;
  update_progress_bar();
});
```

**html**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="button">
  Change bar
</button>

<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 75px; background: #dedede;">
        <div class="progress" style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: 30px;">
            <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ygbgp9b0/) showing what's going on (hit the button 5-6 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `.animate()` method is not that reliable when used with percentages. As an alternative, you could use pixel values like so:

```
function update_progress_bar() {
    var progress = (window.total / window.target),
        new_width = $("#progress-bar").parent().width() * progress;

    $("#progress-bar").animate({
        width: new_width,
    }).text(window.total);
}
```

Alternatively you could drop the .animate() method, and handle the animation with css. You can do that like this:

```
<style>
.progress-bar {
    transition: width 1s;
}
<style>

function update_progress_bar() {
    progress_percent_full = (window.total / window.target) * 100;
    var new_width = progress_percent_full + "%";

    $("#progress-bar").width(new_width).text(total);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks much for your help!